# How do you display data from multiple entries in a mysql table that are JOINED with another via a single value match?

Tags: mysql, atlassian-crowd

I need to select and display information from a pair of MySQL tables but the syntax eludes me. Specifically, I need to JOIN the data from the cwd_user table with the data from the cwd_user_attribute table on the field cwd_user.id == cwd_user_attribute.user_id, but I also need to display values from several entries in the cwd_user_attribute table in a single line. It's the latter that eludes me. Here are the gory details:

Given two tables:

```
mysql (crowd@prod:crowddb)> desc cwd_user;
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                  | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| user_name           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| active              | char(1)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| created_date        | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_date        | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| display_name        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| directory_id        | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+


mysql (crowd@prod:crowddb)> desc cwd_user_attribute;
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                    | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| user_id               | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| directory_id          | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| attribute_name        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| attribute_value       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Assume that there are up to seven possible values for cwd_user_attribute.attribute_name and I'm interested in four of them: lastAuthenticated, Team, Manager Notes. Example:

```
mysql (crowd@prod:crowddb)> select * from cwd_user_attribute where user_id = (select id from cwd_user where user_name = 'gspinrad');
+---------+---------+--------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+
| id      | user_id | directory_id | attribute_name          | attribute_value                  |
+---------+---------+--------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+
|   65788 |   32844 |            1 | invalidPasswordAttempts | 0                                | 
|   65787 |   32844 |            1 | lastAuthenticated       | 1473360428804                    |  
|   65790 |   32844 |            1 | passwordLastChanged     | 1374005378040                    | 
|   65789 |   32844 |            1 | requiresPasswordChange  | false                            | 
| 4292909 |   32844 |            1 | Team                    | Engineering - DevOps             | 
| 4292910 |   32844 |            1 | Manager                 | Matt Karaffa                     |  
| 4292911 |   32844 |            1 | Notes                   | Desk 32:2:11                     | 
+---------+---------+--------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I can get a list of the users sorted by lastAuthenticated with this query:

```
SELECT cwd_user.user_name, cwd_user.id, cwd_user.display_name, from_unixtime(cwd_user_attribute.attribute_value/1000) as last_login FROM cwd_user JOIN cwd_directory ON cwd_user.directory_id = cwd_directory.id JOIN cwd_user_attribute ON cwd_user.id = cwd_user_attribute.user_id AND cwd_user_attribute.attribute_name='lastAuthenticated' WHERE DATEDIFF((NOW()), (from_unixtime(cwd_user_attribute.attribute_value/1000))) > 90 and cwd_user.active='T' order by last_login limit 4;
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| user_name             | id      | display_name          | last_login |
+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| jenkins-administrator | 1605636 | Jenkins Administrator | 2011-10-27 17:28:05 |
| sonar-administrator   | 1605635 | Sonar Administrator   | 2012-02-06 15:59:59 |
| jfelix                | 1605690 | Joey Felix            | 2012-02-06 19:15:15 |
| kbitters              | 3178497 | Kitty Bitters         | 2013-09-03 10:09:59 |
```

What I need to add to the output is the value of cwd_user_attribute.attribute_value where cwd_user_attribute.attribute_name is Team, Manager, and/or Notes. The output would look something like this:

```
+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user_name             | id      | display_name          | last_login          | Team          | Manager      |  Notes       |
+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| jenkins-administrator | 1605636 | Jenkins Administrator | 2011-10-27 17:28:05 | Internal      | Internal     |              | 
| sonar-administrator   | 1605635 | Sonar Administrator   | 2012-02-06 15:59:59 | Internal      | Internal     |              |
| jfelix                | 1605690 | Joey Felix            | 2012-02-06 19:15:15 | Hardware Eng. | Gary Spinrad | Desk 32:1:51 |
| kbitters              | 3178497 | Kitty Bitters         | 2013-09-03 10:09:59 | Software QA   | Matt Karaffa | Desk 32:2:01 |
+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: It sounds like you want a variation of a PIVOT table, where you'd select `user_name`, `attribute_name`, and `attribute_value`. Each `user_name` would obviously appear multiple times (once for each atrribute), but you'd then PIVOT to turn each attribute into a column. Unfortunately my experience lies within SQL Server, however I think this should give you some slight guidance. I apologize I could not be of more help. **Example:** http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/pivot.png (where item_type is your attribute_name and item_amount is your attribute_value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that result with an additional `LEFT JOIN` with the attribute table. Then use `GROUP BY` and aggregated `CASE` statements to pivot the result (rows to columns).

```
SELECT
    cwd_user.user_name,
    cwd_user.id,
    cwd_user.display_name,
    from_unixtime(cwd_user_attribute.attribute_value/1000) as last_login,
    MIN(CASE WHEN attr2.attribute_name = 'TEAM'    THEN attr2.attribute_value END) as Team,
    MIN(CASE WHEN attr2.attribute_name = 'Manager' THEN attr2.attribute_value END) as Manager,
    MIN(CASE WHEN attr2.attribute_name = 'Notes'   THEN attr2.attribute_value END) as Notes
FROM 
    cwd_user 
JOIN 
    cwd_user_attribute ON cwd_user.id = cwd_user_attribute.user_id
                       AND cwd_user_attribute.attribute_name='lastAuthenticated'
LEFT JOIN 
    cwd_user_attribute attr2 ON  cwd_user.id = attr2.user_id
                             AND attr2.attribute_name IN ('Team', 'Manager', 'Notes')
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF((NOW()), (from_unixtime(cwd_user_attribute.attribute_value/1000))) > 90
    AND cwd_user.active = 'T'
GROUP BY 
    cwd_user.id
ORDER BY 
    last_login 
LIMIT 4
```

With strict mode you would need to list all not aggregated columns in the GROUP BY clause

```
GROUP BY 
    cwd_user.user_name,
    cwd_user.id,
    cwd_user.display_name,
    cwd_user_attribute.attribute_value
```

Another way is just to use three LEFT JOINs (one join per attribute name):

```
SELECT
    cwd_user.user_name,
    cwd_user.id,
    cwd_user.display_name,
    from_unixtime(cwd_user_attribute.attribute_value/1000) as last_login,
    attr_team.attribute_value as Team,
    attr_manager.attribute_value as Manager,
    attr_notes.attribute_value as Notes
FROM cwd_user 
JOIN cwd_user_attribute
  ON  cwd_user.id = cwd_user_attribute.user_id
  AND cwd_user_attribute.attribute_name='lastAuthenticated'
LEFT JOIN cwd_user_attribute attr_team
  ON  cwd_user.id = attr2.user_id
  AND attr2.attribute_name = 'Team'
LEFT JOIN cwd_user_attribute attr_manager
  ON  cwd_user.id = attr2.user_id
  AND attr2.attribute_name = 'Manager'
LEFT JOIN cwd_user_attribute attr_notes
  ON  cwd_user.id = attr2.user_id
  AND attr2.attribute_name = 'Notes'
WHERE DATEDIFF((NOW()), (from_unixtime(cwd_user_attribute.attribute_value/1000))) > 90
  and cwd_user.active='T'
order by last_login limit 4
```

Note: I have removed the join with directory table because you seem not to use it. Add it again, if you need it for filtering.

Note 2: Some attributes that you often use for a search (like `lastAuthenticated`) should be converted to indexed columns in the users table to improve the search performance.